# webview showing white screen on android before version 5 kitkat and icecream and stuck on it

Tags: android, webview, screen

I have developed a simple app using Android Studio to do live streaming using an `HLS link`. The application is working fine on the `version 5` and above, but most of the versions below that reporting having a white screen only. Using the emulator, it works fine with the APIs 21, 22 and 23, but with 15, 16 and 17 it is showing white screen. Below is my activity code.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    import com.example.webview.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
private View mCustomView;
private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
    mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/live/xx/playlist.m3u8");
}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    webView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    if (inCustomView()) {
        hideCustomView();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
            return true;
        }

        if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View mVideoProgressView;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mCustomView = view;
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewContainer.addView(view);
        customViewCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

        mCustomView = null;
    }
}

class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?